# Write concern in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, high-availability

In MongoDB it is called write concern, that is the number of the servers in a replica set, that the data should be committed before the cluster acknowledges the write request. How is it called in the Postgres?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostgreSQL works differently. As soon as the data are committed on the single primary database, the write is effective. If you use synchronous replication, that commit waits until the required standby servers (configured by [`synchronous_standby_names`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-replication.html#GUC-SYNCHRONOUS-STANDBY-NAMES)) have received the information.