# Can PostgresSQL cluster have synchronus and asyncronus standbys at the same time for the same dbs?

Tags: postgresql, replication, clustering, postgresql-performance, semi-sync-replication

In this question, [Write concern in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/267400/write-concern-in-postgresql/267407#267407) [Laurenz Albe](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/176905/laurenz-albe) explained how to control the set of standby servers when data is committed to PostgresSQL, and that gave birth to another question. What if I want to have N standbys, and want to have synchronous replication enabled for some M subset of N, is that possible? A use case could be a cold backup. I don't care of data inconsistency for N-M subset, I just need to have that on M subset of N standbys.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

There is a setting for this which is called [synchronous_standby_names](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-replication.html#GUC-SYNCHRONOUS-STANDBY-NAMES).

You can give expression like `ANY 3 (r1, r2, r3, r4)` which says "proceed commit as soon as at least any three standbys reply"

If you want to specify exact replication name just name them like `r1,r4`.

Here is sample usage;

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET synchronous_standby_names TO 'ANY 3 (r1, r2, r3, r4)';
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

**Note**: The standby names (which are r1,r2..) are defined by [application_name](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-APPLICATION-NAME) option of standby's [primary_conninfo](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-replication.html#GUC-PRIMARY-CONNINFO) setting value.